# MWPhotoBrowser Blank Screen/Delegate Methods Not Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on an IOS project where I need to be able to segue into a ViewController that contains the MWPhotoBrowser.

Currently, I have created a PhotoGalleryController and used that as a container for MWPhotoBrowser since MWPhotoBrowser is a subclass of UIViewController.

However, when I launch the application in the simulator, I get a blank screen with a circle in the middle, suggesting that the PhotoBrowser was loaded but there is no photo being returned.

I went ahead and logged all my delegate methods and found that numberOfPhotos was being called but the actual functions that were supposed to return MWPhoto objects were never even called!

I'm not quite sure why the actual loading of the photo objects is never completed even though I have implemented all the proper delegate methods within the container ViewController.

I checked the output of the response given by the API call and printed out self.photoList as well. Those seem to be fine so I'm not sure why it doesn't return any photos.

**PhotoGalleryController.m**

```
#import "PhotoGalleryController.h"
#import "MZApi.h"
#import "MZUser.h"

@implementation PhotoGalleryController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //Make the HTTP request and setup the photo array in MZUser. Change from "usertext" later. 
    [MZApi loadOwnPhotoWithUserID:@"usertext" andCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *photos, NSError *error) {
        if(photos!=nil){
            self.userPhotoList = photos;
            [[MZUser getCurrentUser]setPhotoList:self.userPhotoList];
            //NSLog(@" %@", self.userPhotoList);
            //Should currently be null because CurrentUser is not created yet.
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to allocate photos!");
        }

    }];


    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc]initWithDelegate:self];



    browser.displayActionButton = YES; // Show action button to allow sharing, copying, etc (defaults to YES)
    browser.displayNavArrows = NO; // Whether to display left and right nav arrows on toolbar (defaults to NO)
    browser.displaySelectionButtons = NO; // Whether selection buttons are shown on each image (defaults to NO)
    browser.enableGrid = YES; // Whether to allow the viewing of all the photo thumbnails on a grid (defaults to YES)
    browser.startOnGrid = YES; // Whether to start on the grid of thumbnails instead of the first photo (defaults to NO)
    [self.view addSubview:browser.view];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSUInteger) numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser{
    return [self.userPhotoList count];

}
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    if(index<self.userPhotoList.count){
        NSString *temp = [[self.userPhotoList objectAtIndex:index]file_url];
        MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
        return photo;
    }
    return nil;
}
-(id <MWPhoto>) photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    NSLog(@"Thumb Delegate Called!");
    if(index<self.userPhotoList.count){
        NSString *temp = [[self.userPhotoList objectAtIndex:index]file_url];
        MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
        return photo;
    }
    return nil;
}


@end
```

**PhotoGalleryController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"

@interface PhotoGalleryController : UIViewController <MWPhotoBrowserDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * userPhotoList;

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser;
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

Server Response Sample:

```
(
        {
        dislikes = 0;
        "file_url" = "http://localhost:3000/static/photos/2.jpg";
        likes = 0;
        "photo_id" = 2;
        "user_id" = kai1234;
    },
        {
        dislikes = 4;
        "file_url" = "http://localhost:3000/static/photos/1.jpg";
        likes = 5;
        "photo_id" = 1;
        "user_id" = kai1234;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding browser to view when you're loading photos with block, normally there is delay when you load photos with block, so browser will get an empty object.

your code should look like

```
#import "PhotoGalleryController.h"
#import "MZApi.h"
#import "MZUser.h"

@implementation PhotoGalleryController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //Make the HTTP request and setup the photo array in MZUser. Change from "usertext" later. 

    self.userPhotoList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [MZApi loadOwnPhotoWithUserID:@"usertext" andCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *photos, NSError *error) {
        if(photos!=nil){
            self.userPhotoList = photos;
            [[MZUser getCurrentUser] setPhotoList:self.userPhotoList];
            //NSLog(@" %@", self.userPhotoList);
            //Should currently be null because CurrentUser is not created yet.

            for (int i = 0; i < photos.count; i++)
            {
                [self.userPhotoList addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[photos objectAtIndex:i] file_url]]];
            }

            MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
            browser.displayActionButton = YES; // Show action button to allow sharing, copying, etc (defaults to YES)
            browser.displayNavArrows = NO; // Whether to display left and right nav arrows on toolbar (defaults to NO)
            browser.displaySelectionButtons = NO; // Whether selection buttons are shown on each image (defaults to NO)
            browser.enableGrid = YES; // Whether to allow the viewing of all the photo thumbnails on a grid (defaults to YES)
            browser.startOnGrid = YES; // Whether to start on the grid of thumbnails instead of the first photo (defaults to NO)
            [self.view addSubview:browser.view];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to allocate photos!");
        }

    }];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSUInteger) numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser{
    return [self.userPhotoList count];

}
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    if(index<self.userPhotoList.count){
        return [self.userPhotoList objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}
-(id <MWPhoto>) photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    NSLog(@"Thumb Delegate Called!");
    if(index<self.userPhotoList.count){
        return [self.userPhotoList objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: I just tried this solution. Apart from the commenting out the self.userPhotoList = photos, I get invalid context. I think this is because calling self.view from within the block refers to MZApi rather than the ViewController.

Comment: Calling self.view within the block refers to your viewcontroller's view, this code is just getting called after response is received, can u paste how your server response looks like ? I didn't get what file_url refers to

Comment: file_url goes to a link that points to a picture served on a static filesystem.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the server response.
Apr 17 19:16:16  RateMyFashion[38275] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
This is the feedback from XCode after using your code.

Comment: Those photos are accessible from simulator's safari ? I guess not